# Mozilla translates <br></br> as <br></br><br></br>

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, browser, line-breaks

Our CMS outputs linebreaks as `<br></br>` (stupid, i know, but syntactically corrent(?))

This translates to `<br><br>` in chrome and IE10 and to `<br></br><br></br>` in Firefox.

All browsers shows it as two linebreaks.

Why are not `<br></br>` translated like `<br />` or just `<br>`, is there something i can do 
to make browser interpret `<br></br>` as just one linebreak?

Comment: `br` is an inline tag. Meaning it has no closing tag. You must use it as `<br/>`

Comment: As the answers indicate, `<br></br>` is _not_ syntactically correct. Sure, it is well-formed XML, so it would work in XHTML; only real XHTML though, with a xml content-type. It is, however, invalid. So your question, "is there something i can do to make browser interpret <br></br> as just one linebreak?" is the wrong question; it actually should be: "how can I get rid of the `</br>`?"

Comment: PS if you could manage to give the documents a content-type of `application/xhtml+xml`, you would see that it does indeed come out as intended. It still should be `<br />` though.

Answer (score 3):

It's defined by the HTML5 specifications: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inbody (search the text `An end tag whose tag name is "br"` in the page).

If your document is parsed as an HTML document, each closing `br` tag will be always parsed as if it was an opening tag (and creates an element with no content). But if you parse your document as an XHTML document a `<br></br>` sequence will produce the same DOM tree as the `<br/>` tag. To have your document parsed as an XHTML document, you have to send it with the `application/xhtml+xml` mime type.

More details are available in the specifications: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml; http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html.

Comment: "each closing br tag will be always parsed as if it was an opening tag". Hmm, yes that's what the spec says. But it's not quite what browsers do. Consider `</br class="x">`. The resulting element will not have the class attribute. I've raised a bug on the spec requesting clarification.

Comment: Note that the [HTML 5.1 spec draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#parsing-main-inbody) has now been modified to say that any attributes on the br end tag will be dropped.

Comment: Only for completeness, I want to leave the URL of the bug filed by @Alohci: https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=24233.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question... seeing as your CMS seems to output this abomination, if you need a quick fix...

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/P6bDp/

Bonus CSS selector list - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

CSS

```
br + br {display: none;}
```

This will eliminate the second `<br>` and leave a single line break. Fix that CMS though :)

Answer (score 1):

hey `<br></br>` is not syntactically correct, you must use it as `<br/>` (look at the slash). its inline element so no need to close like other elements. it closes itself

Comment: Hell, even the slash is not required unless you want to adhere to the XHTML spec. HTML5 has [no such requirement](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element).

Comment: Well, I guess I'll write an email to the cms guys then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MisterManSam- Agree :) And guys please look at Carlo Cannas's answer